# Android Alarmmanager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a service that I would like to be executed daily in my application. The service should only be executed **ONCE** per day. For some reason my service gets fired several times throughout the day, I do not know what is going on. Here is my alarmmanger set up:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(this,ReviewReceiver.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));


Random random = new Random();
int hour = random.nextInt(22 - 7) + 7;
int minute = random.nextInt(60 - 1) + 1;
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,5);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,5);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent );
```

I have set the alarm to randomly set itself between 7 am and 10 pm upon installation of the application.

So for example, when the alarm sets itself at 13h30, the service will be fired at that time properly. But therafter, it will get fired over and over at random intervals throughout the day. What am I doing wrong. Please help.

*P.S. I have already tried using `ELAPSED_TIME, ELAPSED_TIME_WAKEUP` and they do not work*

Comment: try setRepeating instead of setInexactRepeating

Comment: Under which version of android are you testing your code ?

Comment: Try out this: don't make set hours and minutes randomly instead set them to some future values e.g. If current time is 13:15 then set alarm for 13:30 and check that service is running more once than once or not.

Comment: @Carnal i have changed it to that, and so far it has been behaving, ill have to wait and see if it does not misbehave for the rest of the day.

Comment: @VVJ I have set it to a fixed time and I will see if it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

For Lollipop and greater (M preview also have this behavior), the alarm have a strange behavior if you don't set it in the future and at least adding 5s.

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    now + 5s,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    pendingIntent );
```

[The 5s is a known issue.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82001) and since this problem occurred (especially with my nexus 5), I am just using `set()` that a recall every day instead of `setInexactRepeating()`